# InvalidRequestException of status code 400 when AWS Lambda Function was invoked

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

```js
var config = {};
config.IOT_BROKER_ENDPOINT = "abcdefghijk.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com".toLowerCase();
config.IOT_BROKER_REGION = "us-east-1";
config.IOT_THING_2 = "Thing1";
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = config.IOT_BROKER_REGION;
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', secretAccessKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'});
var iotdata = new AWS.IotData({endpoint: config.IOT_BROKER_ENDPOINT});
// namespaces
const NAMESPACE_CONTROL = "Alexa.ConnectedHome.Control";
const NAMESPACE_DISCOVERY = "Alexa.ConnectedHome.Discovery";

// discovery
const REQUEST_DISCOVER = "DiscoverAppliancesRequest";
const RESPONSE_DISCOVER = "DiscoverAppliancesResponse";

// control
const REQUEST_TURN_ON = "TurnOnRequest";
const RESPONSE_TURN_ON = "TurnOnConfirmation";
const REQUEST_TURN_OFF = "TurnOffRequest";
const RESPONSE_TURN_OFF = "TurnOffConfirmation";

// errors
const ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION = "UnsupportedOperationError";
const ERROR_UNEXPECTED_INFO = "UnexpectedInformationReceivedError";

// entry

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
  log("Received Directive", event);
  var requestedNamespace = event.header.namespace;
  var response = null;

  try {
    switch (requestedNamespace) {
      case NAMESPACE_DISCOVERY:
        response = handleDiscovery(event);
        break;
      case NAMESPACE_CONTROL:
        response = handleControl(event);
        break;
      default:
        log("Error", "Unsupported namespace: " + requestedNamespace);
        response = handleUnexpectedInfo(requestedNamespace);
        break;
    }// switch
  } catch (error) {
    log("Error", error);
  }// try-catch

  callback(null, response);
}// exports.handler


var handleDiscovery = function (event) {

  var header = createHeader(NAMESPACE_DISCOVERY, RESPONSE_DISCOVER);
  var payload = {
    "discoveredAppliances": [],
  };
  return createDirective(header, payload);
}// handleDiscovery

var handleControl = function (event) {

  var response = null;
  var requestedName = event.header.name;

  switch (requestedName) {
    case REQUEST_TURN_ON :
      response = handleControlTurnOn(event);
      break;
    case REQUEST_TURN_OFF :
      response = handleControlTurnOff(event);
      break;
    default:
      log("Error", "Unsupported operation" + requestedName);
      response = handleUnsupportedOperation();
      break;
  }// switch

  return response;
}// handleControl

var handleControlTurnOn = function (event) {
  var thingPicker = config.IOT_THING_2;
  console.log("Turning On the LED now");
  console.log("check 1");
  var update = {
    "desired": {
      "led": 1,
    },
  };
  console.log("check 2");
  console.log(thingPicker);
  iotdata.updateThingShadow({
    payload: JSON.stringify(update),
    thingName: thingPicker,
  }, function (err, data) {
    console.log("check 4");
    if (err) {
      console.log("check 5");
      console.log(err);

    } else {
      console.log("check 6");
      console.log(data);
    }
  });

  var header = createHeader(NAMESPACE_CONTROL, RESPONSE_TURN_ON);

  var payload = {};

  return createDirective(header, payload);

}// handleControlTurnOn


var handleControlTurnOff = function (event) {
  var thingPicker = config.IOT_THING_2;
  console.log("Turning Off the LED now");
  var update = {

    "desired": {
      "led": 0,
    },

  };
  console.log(thingPicker);
  iotdata.updateThingShadow({
    payload: JSON.stringify(update),
    thingName: thingPicker,
  }, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });

  var header = createHeader(NAMESPACE_CONTROL, RESPONSE_TURN_OFF);

  var payload = {};

  return createDirective(header, payload);

}// handleControlTurnOff


var handleUnsupportedOperation = function () {

  var header = createHeader(NAMESPACE_CONTROL, ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION);
  var payload = {};
  return createDirective(header, payload);

}// handleUnsupportedOperation


var handleUnexpectedInfo = function (fault) {

  var header = createHeader(NAMESPACE_CONTROL, ERROR_UNEXPECTED_INFO);
  var payload = {
    "faultingParameter": fault,
  };
  return createDirective(header, payload);
}// handleUnexpectedInfo


// support functions

var createMessageId = function () {

  var d = new Date().getTime();
  var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
    var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
    d = Math.floor(d / 16);
    return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
  });
  return uuid;
}// createMessageId


var createHeader = function (namespace, name) {
  return {
    "messageId": createMessageId(),
    "namespace": namespace,
    "name": name,
    "payloadVersion": "2",
  };
}// createHeader


var createDirective = function (header, payload) {
  return {
    "header": header,
    "payload": payload,
  };
}// createDirective


var log = function (title, msg) {
  console.log('**** ' + title + ': ' + JSON.stringify(msg));
}// log
```

Piece of code related to AWS Lambda Function which is of smart home API, when it was run against a testing event to turn on light, its giving "InvalidRequestException" of status code :400

the test event that was run against the code was:

```
{
 "header": {
  "messageId" : "5d599a53-fe40-405f-b0ab-233611e2dc5c",
  "name" : "TurnOnRequest",
  "namespace" : "Alexa.ConnectedHome.Control",
  "payloadVersion" : "2"
 },
 "payload" : {
  "accessToken" : "acc355t0ken"
 }
}
```

Can any one please help me solve that exception.
Thanks in advance

Comment: 400 is bad request. What was the actual response body ? It sounds like you failed schema validation, or forgot to send a required field.

Comment: In response to the request that was given like above : { [InvalidRequestException: Missing required node: state]
  message: 'Missing required node: state',
  code: 'InvalidRequestException',
  time: Wed Mar 01 2017 08:02:05 GMT+0000 (UTC),
  requestId: '6ae2f206-ed7d-f5f9-0108-a8b4f4ea8dc8',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,

Comment: You need to send state. Example https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=725536

Comment: Thank you so much, It's now printing data... it worked.Thanks a LOT! :)

Comment: Now that lamda function is reporting state and it's working perfectly fine from the AWS account, but Alexa app in the mobile phone and the Amazon echo-dot are unable to discover devices.