# AWS IoT 1 Click Project SAM - 400 InvalidRequestException error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-iot, aws-sam

Hi I am using AWS SAM to deploy a serverless application that also relies on 1Click devices I have the template deploying fine but I have to exclude this value:

```
CallbackOverrides:
              onClickCallback:
```

here is the template file

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: securitybutton
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 10
Resources:
  SecurityButtonFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Policies:
      - AmazonSNSFullAccess
    Properties:
      CodeUri: src
      Handler: index.lambdaHandler,
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      MemorySize: 512
      Events:
        IoTRule:
          Type: IoTRule
          Properties:
            Sql: SELECT * FROM 'iotbutton/*'
 #TOPICS
  BRSecurityButtonTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic

#IoT
#project
  BRSecurityButtonProject:
    Type: "AWS::IoT1Click::Project"
    Properties:
      ProjectName: "BRSecurityButton"
      Description: "BRSecurityButton"
      PlacementTemplate:
        DefaultAttributes:
          SNSTopic: Changeme
          Location: Changeme
          Theatre: Changeme
        DeviceTemplates:
          SecuityButtonTemplate:
            DeviceType: "button"
            CallbackOverrides:
              onClickCallback: !GetAtt 
                - SecurityButtonFunction
                - Arn
Outputs:
  SecurityButtonFunction:
    Description: "Security Button Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt SecurityButtonFunction.Arn
```

Here is the resulting cloudFormation error:

> Lambda function
> arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:LALALALALALA:function:securitybutton-prod-SecurityButtonFunction-6OB47JEIU192
> cannot be invoked. (Service: AWSIoT1ClickProjects; Status Code: 400;
> Error Code: InvalidRequestException; Request ID:
> f0e94cd5-0310-4dcf-8d4a-a5ee8b102590; Proxy: null)

on the logical ID of BRSecurityButtonProject

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you check your cloudwatch logs for an error (find the log group with a name matching to your function name). Maybe it will have more details.

Comment: See this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42525435/invalidrequestexception-of-status-code-400-when-aws-lambda-function-was-invoked

Comment: Hey there is nothing in cloudwatch because the template is trying to deploy. This error is coming from Cloudformation not Lambda execution itself

Comment: how are you doing the "deploy"?  You dont tell us what command you run.  And what was its output ?

Comment: I am using a custom bitbucket pipeline to push the cloudformation template over and then AWS runs the cloudformation stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the issue was related to IAM. Added this to the SAM template, which granted access for any IoT 1-click projects in the account to invoke the Lambda function.

```
  SecurityButtonFunctionIoTPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !GetAtt SecurityButtonFunction.Arn
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      Principal: iot1click.amazonaws.com
      SourceAccount: !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
```